# How do I do this simple URL rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

What URL rewrite rule should I put in .htaccess to re-write this:

```
http://www...com/one/john
```

into this:

```
http://www...com/one/two/index.php?profile=john
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it. Anything following `/one` that doesn't include a `/` will be passed into the `profile` parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^one/([^/]+)$ /one/two/index.php?profile=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks... what file should the .htaccess file be in? ("two", "one", or file above "one"?

Comment: @John The .htaccess file should be at the document root `/` in this case.

Comment: It works, however all of the CSS is gone.  Any idea how I can get the CSS to work?

Comment: @John Links to css and other resources (images/js/etc) have to be relative to the website root (start with slash) e.g. `<img src="/images/logo.png" />` and not `<img src="../images/logo.png" />` or similar.

Comment: @John see addition of `RewriteCond` above. Should prevent your actually existing image and css files from being subject to the rewrite